# При запуске программы C# COMBOBOX не показывает данные из БД типа SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
   public WindowAlbumEditAdd(string id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadCmbGroup();
            LoadCmbCountrys();
            LoadCmbDistruts();
            LoadCmbStudios();
            f = 1;
            _id = id;
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Album.name_Album, Album.date_zap, " +
                    "Album.date_sale, Group_.name_Group, Country.ter_raspr, Studio.name_studio, Distrub.name_Distrud " +
                    "FROM Album " +
                    "INNER JOIN Group_ ON Album.group_id = Group_.id_Group " +
                    "INNER JOIN Country ON Album.country_id = Country.id_Country " +
                    "INNER JOIN Studio ON Album.studio_id = Studio.id_Studio " +
                    $"INNER JOIN Distrub ON Album.distrub_id = Distrub.id_Distrub WHERE id_album = '{_id}'", sqlConnection);
                SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tbName.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                        dtZap.SelectedDate = reader.GetDateTime(1);
                        dtSale.SelectedDate = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                        cmbGroup.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id);
                        cmbCountry.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id);
                        cmbStudio.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id);
                        cmbDistrub.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Только почему то не работает cmbGroup.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id); не понимаю почему
_id это ID записи

Comment: Так ..., что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @AzizUmarov что бы в combobox при открытие окна уже там были данные типа из бд если конечно в бд есть данные а у меня есть в бд данные но там ничего не появляется

Comment: А почему это `cmbGroup.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(_id);` должно быть в цикле ридера? Может мух от котлет все ж таки лучше отделять? Есть работа с данными в БД, и есть работа с юзер.интерфейсом. `int.Parse(_id);` надо было сделать один раз сразу в первой строке метода, а потом уже назначать  готовое числовое значение комбобоксам. И кстати вы же в самом начале загружаете данные в комбобоксы, почему сразу там и не выделить нужный элемент?